# Is Ruby file deletion asynchronous?

Tags: ruby

I have (had) some Ruby code which for historical reasons is (was) essentially

```rb
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  path_list = something_which_creates_files_in(dir)
  path_list.each(&:delete)
end
```

Occasionally I get (got) exceptions from this code:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_s_rmdir - /tmp/d2..4w/file.csv
  :
  /path/to/source.rb:124:in `unlink'
  /path/to/source.rb:124:in `delete'
  /path/to/source.rb:124:in `each'
  :
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
  :
```

so it *appears* to me that that my "cleanup" of the list of paths at the end of the block is not entirely synchronous, that (some of) the files still exist after it completes, then `mktmpdir` removes the temporary directory so that the asynchronous (?) `unlink` fails, its target has gone away.  Is this a reasonable interpretation?

This is more an academic question than anything else; the behaviour puzzles me.  Just removing the cleanup (the `path_list.each(&:delete)`) and leaving the deletion to `Dir.mktmpdir` seems to stop these exceptions.

If it makes a difference, this is Ruby 2.5 (MRI) running on Linux.

Comment: Any chance that `something_which_creates_files_in` returns the same filename twice?

Comment: Actually no, the details of the implementation calculated a hash with the path as keys and just returned those, so necessarily unique.

Comment: This is very likely not an issue of concurrency nor implementation details of the block form of `Dir.mktmpdir`. Instead, "something" deletes the file before your `.each(&:delete)` comes to it. Either one of the named file was never created in the first place or it was deleted before by some code you have not shown, or you do some strange multi-threaded stuff to keep file references in a separate thread (the last case would likely be non-deterministic and occur only sometimes). In any case, the error apparently occurs BEFORE any of the cleanup of `Dir.mktmpdir` even started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption seems to be correct.

If you would check the source of `File.unlink` you could see the following:

```c
static VALUE
rb_file_s_unlink(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE klass)
{
    return apply2files(unlink_internal, argc, argv, 0);
}
```

Here `unlink_internal` is a trivial thing (just a thin wrapper around a system call?), but what is interesting is the implementation of `apply2files`. You could see [there](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/file.c#L430) the following call:

```c
...
rb_thread_call_without_gvl(no_gvl_apply2files, aa, RUBY_UBF_IO, 0);
...
```

where `aa` is some fancy struct that contains among other things a pointer to the thing that we want to apply - `unlink` in our case.

The name of this function is quite self-descriptive, but the source contains some documentation too, so we can just [refer to it](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/thread.c#L1705):

```
/*
 * rb_thread_call_without_gvl - permit concurrent/parallel execution.
 * rb_thread_call_without_gvl2 - permit concurrent/parallel execution
 *                               without interrupt process.
...
```

So from what I see (disclaimer: without the really careful analysis of the source code :)) the deletions within the block in question 1) do happen concurrently and 2) without GIL "protection" - so "surprises" are more than possible if one tries to delete temporary files twice (1st time explicitly and 2nd time implicitly when the `mktmpdir` block exits).

Comment: That's fabulous, thank you.

Comment: Note that this is highly dependent on the specific Ruby implementation being used, which the OP unfortunately has not specified. For example, it looks very different in [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/file.rb#L1058-L1065), [TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/file.rb#L1091-L1098), [Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/stdlib/nodejs/file.rb#L138-L144), [JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyFile.java#L1309-L1330), or …

Comment: … [MRuby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrbgems/mruby-io/src/file.c#L115-L136).

Comment: @JörgWMittag you're absolutely right, but MRI wins with such a huge margin when it comes to different implementations' share in the real world, that it is quite safe to assume MRI unless something else is explicitly specified :)

Comment: In fact it is MRI, I've updated the question to mention that -- thanks